# routing error using omniauth and custom user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I have a custom `User` model and authentication via `omniauth-facebook` and `omniauth-vkontakte`. The authentication is needed to leave comments to `Post` model and review to `Book` model. So I defined a `sessions_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    cookies[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

and in `show.html.erb` of both the `Book` and `Post` models I have the following:

```
<div>
    <p>Only signed in users can leave comments/reviews. 
    Please sign in via <%= link_to 'Facebook', 'auth/facebook' %> or
    <%= link_to 'VK', 'auth/vkontakte' %> </p>
</div>
```

and in `routes.rb` I have this:

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

the console returns the following error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/books/auth/facebook")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the dumbest: I should have written `<%= link_to ... '/auth/:strategy'`, so I just missed the initial slash!